# Create dummy equal to one if string vector equal to element in multiple string vector

Tags: r

In R, I want to set a [61,1] dummy vector a equal to one if the elements in one string vector [61,1] b matches the element in 3 [1,1] string vectors c1, c2, c3.

I've tried something like:

```
for(i in 1:3) { 
  data$a[data$b==data2$ci]<-1
}
```

without success.

To make it clear, the data looks something like (couldn't make column vectors, so think of the transpose of these):

```r
Data
a 0 0 0 0 0 ... 0
b M M D M X ... E

Data2
c1 M
c2 X
c3 P
```

I want "a" to look like:

```
a 1 1 0 1 1 ... 0
```

EDIT:

This code works:

```
data$a <- ifelse(data$b %in% data2$p1, 1, 
                          ifelse(data$b %in% data2$p2, 1,
                                 ifelse(data$b %in% data2$p3, 1, 0)))
```

However, I'm sure that there is a more efficient solution using a loop. If there were more than three variables, (e.g., c1, c2, ... c99), then a lot of repetitive code would have to be written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the easiest approach is to use an ifelse statement. Please add a reproducible example in your next question to make it easier for those trying to give you solutions.

```
Data <- data.frame(a = 0,
               b = c("M", "M", "D", "M", "X", "P"),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Data2 <- data.frame(a = c("c1", "c2", "c3"),
                    b = c("M", "X", "P"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Data$a <- ifelse(Data$b %in% Data2$b, 1, 0)
```

The %in% operator evaluates whether each element in the vector on the left hand side is present in the vector on the right. It outputs a logical vector that is used to define whether to assign a 1 or 0 in this case.